# Do older Dawes cycles use standard components?

Tags: frames

I'd like to built a commuter/utility/messaround type bike. I like hub gears, and I want a steel frame.

I've been looking at older Dawes bikes. Specifically a 'Streetwise' or Galaxy.

I know some have 135 OLN already (though I'll have to check before I buy). Are all other components standard? Meaning headset dia and threading, bottom bracket, brake mounts, mudguard and rack mounts etc.

I've already been caught out with the non standard-ness of older Raleigh and Peugeot bikes,

Many thanks.

Comment: For the uninitiated, what vintage (years of production) is meant by "older"?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about old Galaxies, but in the case of the Streetwise, possibly not. I once restored an old Dawes and found it a bit of a nightmare - for a start the seat tube was an odd diameter which made fitting the front mech interesting. The seatpost was 26.8mm which is not unheard of but does limit your options. The headset was the old JIS type (Japanese Industrial Standard, I think) which had slightly different diameters (head tube 30mm, crown race 27mm) to a standard 1" threaded (30.2/27.4). And finally the rear mech was fixed on with a strange bolt-through arrangement which meant that the threads for the mech hangar had never been used, and needed tapping as they were covered in paint.

So basically don't count on it :)